# UiPath json response to data table

Tags: json, datatable, format, uipath

I have the following lines as a json reply to my api request:

```
{"attributes":{"completionDate":"2022-11-09T14:34:32Z","errorMessage":null,"id":"0LG9E000001K6JhWAK","ownerId":"0051i000001TNnIAAW","queryable":false,"reportId":"00O9E0000011XLpUAM","reportName":"Test-Report","requestDate":"2022-11-09T14:33:56Z","showDetailedErrorToUser":false,"status":"Success","type":"ReportInstance"},"allData":true,"factMap":{"T!T":{"aggregates":[{"label":"4","value":4}],"rows":[{"dataCells":[{"label":"amotIQ automotive GmbH","value":"0011i00000HkIWDAA3"},{"label":"16.07.2022","value":"2022-07-16"},{"escapedLabel":"Str. 6","label":"Str. 6","value":"Str. 6"}]},{"dataCells":[{"label":"solutions GmbH","value":"0011i00000HkebaAAB"},{"label":"16.07.2022","value":"2022-07-16"},{"escapedLabel":"Str. 20","label":"Str. 20","value":"Str. 20"}]},{"dataCells":[{"label":"systemberatung GmbH","value":"0011i00000H5YIyAAN"},{"label":"16.07.2022","value":"2022-07-16"},{"escapedLabel":"Konrad-Zuse-Platz","label":"Konrad-Zuse-Platz","value":"Konrad-Zuse-Platz"}]},{"dataCells":[{"label":"Systemberatung GmbH","value":"0011i00000HdG3iAAF"},{"label":"16.07.2022","value":"2022-07-16"},{"escapedLabel":"Winklerring","label":"Winklerring","value":"Winklerring"}]}]}},"groupingsAcross":{"groupings":[]},"groupingsDown":{"groupings":[]},"hasDetailRows":true,"picklistColors":{},"reportExtendedMetadata":{"aggregateColumnInfo":{"RowCount":{"dataType":"int","label":"Record Count"}},"availableDashboardSettings":null,"detailColumnInfo":{"ACCOUNT.NAME":{"dataType":"string","filterValues":[],"filterable":true,"inactiveFilterValues":[],"isLookup":true,"label":"Account Name"},"LAST_UPDATE":{"dataType":"date","filterValues":[],"filterable":true,"inactiveFilterValues":[],"isLookup":false,"label":"Last Modified Date"},"ADDRESS1_STREET":{"dataType":"string","filterValues":[],"filterable":true,"inactiveFilterValues":[],"isLookup":false,"label":"Billing Street"}},"groupingColumnInfo":{}},"reportMetadata":{"aggregates":["RowCount"],"chart":null,"crossFilters":[],"currency":null,"dashboardSetting":null,"description":null,"detailColumns":["ACCOUNT.NAME","LAST_UPDATE","ADDRESS1_STREET"],"developerName":"TestReport_xNA","division":null,"folderId":"00D9E000000A3FeUAK","groupingsAcross":[],"groupingsDown":[],"hasDetailRows":true,"hasRecordCount":true,"historicalSnapshotDates":[],"id":"00O9E0000011XLpUAM","name":"Test-Report-Amotiq","presentationOptions":{"hasStackedSummaries":true},"reportBooleanFilter":null,"reportFilters":[{"column":"ACCOUNT.NAME","filterType":"fieldValue","isRunPageEditable":true,"operator":"contains","value":"amotiq"}],"reportFormat":"TABULAR","reportType":{"label":"Accounts","type":"AccountList"},"scope":"organization","showGrandTotal":true,"showSubtotals":true,"sortBy":[],"standardDateFilter":{"column":"CREATED_DATE","durationValue":"CUSTOM","endDate":null,"startDate":null},"standardFilters":null,"supportsRoleHierarchy":false,"userOrHierarchyFilterId":null}}
```

How can I get the returned data into a data table?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**deserialize-json**](https://Use%20the%20https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/deserialize-json).

Then use the for each to iterate through the JObjects.

Finally, use [**add-data-row**](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/lang-de/docs/add-data-row) to prepare the adding of the JSON data into a datatable.